# DirectSound/FFDShow without a Sound Card

Tags: windows, 64-bit, directsound, ffdshow

I've got an application that uses DirectShow/DirectSound which plays videos and extracts the video/sound. Running it on a server without a soundcard means the audio cannot be grabbed, is there a way around this? I look briefly at Virtual Audio Cable 4 but that doesn't seem to emulate a soundcard over a terminal session..

The tricky part of this is that it's running on x64 so i maybe somewhat limited..

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VAC does do the trick but it's somewhat limited in that it doesn't work when you connect to the server through a RDP session.

For the moment I've worked around the issue by starting the process over VNC...

Comment: Does it not work even when you play with the remote audio options in the RDP client?

Comment: Nope, not at all. If i open up the audio properties it says "No Direct Sound Device"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but, make sure you set the "RDP -> option -> local resources ->  remote computer sound" to "live at remote computer" otherwise you can't find any audio randers.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work unless you have a physical sound-device